# How to set fixed ip address for container using docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

**Problem**

I am connecting my java program to mysql but every time the ip adress of mysql container will be keep on changing. If it changes, i have to update that ip address in my java program for connection.(i have mentioned 172.17.0.2 in java program as mysql container ip).

**Below is my simple jdbc java program**

```java
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.lang.*;

public class Sample
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;

        String sql= "select * from student1;";    //insert into student1 values(2,'kalam'); 
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        } 

        try{
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://172.17.0.2:3306/university", "root", "root");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();

            //stmt.execute(sql);
            ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            while(rs.next())
            {
                System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+" "+rs.getString(2)); 
            }
            System.out.println("value inserted");

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e+"driver man");
        }
        finally
        { 
            try{
                if(stmt!=null)
                    stmt.close();

                if(conn!=null)
                    conn.close();
            }
            catch(SQLException e)
            {
                System.out.println(" conn problem");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

**Below is my docker-compose**

```
 mysql:
   image: mysqlrep
   container_name: mysqlcompose
   environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD= root
   ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:3306:3306"
   command: bash -c "/etc/init.d/mysql start && cd /var/lib/mysql && mysql -u root && sleep 10"

java:
   image: java:9
   container_name: javacompose
   links:
      - mysql
   command: bash -c "javac /compose/Sample.java && java -cp "./compose:./compose/mysql-connector-java-5.1.5-bin.jar" Sample"
   volumes: 
      - ~/compose:/compose
```

I am using my own image called mysqlrep in mysql service inside docker compose.(i builded mysqlrep image using dockerfile which contains- mysql-server and i created my Database university, table called student1, inserted the values to it through my.sql file).

**Now i have to set fixed ip address for mysql container so that i can provide it in my java program for connection(bcz it reduces the task to my client). 
How can i set it ?**

**Note:**

- I am using Docker toolbox on windows 7
- docker version:

  - client version: 1.11.1, Os/Arch: windows/amd64
  - server version: 1.11.2, Os/Arch: linux/amd64
- docker-compose version: 1.7.1

Please suggest...

Comment: did you try simply using `mysql` as the hostname instead of an IP? If it's on the same docker-compose network, that should work.

Comment: Yep. Use names instead. Using IP literals is a bad idea since private networks in IPv4 aren't standardized, and some networks might be using the IP range the Docker containers were on previously, which means Docker has to use different networks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the container alias `mysql` to form the connection url from the java container

```java
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/university", ...
```

Comment: @ShashankG, if _it has worked_, please accept the answer.